# Size of sets with complete double

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, sumsets, sidon-sets

Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$. A subset $S\subseteq [n]$ is said to have complete double if $S+S=[2n]$. Let $m(n)$ be the smallest size of a subset of $[n]$ with complete double. My questions are:

> Question 1: has this function been studied before? Any reference? It looks related to [Sidon sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence), but not quite the same.
>
> Question 2: It is easy to see that $m(n)\geq 2\sqrt{n}-1$. Can we show that $m(n)\approx 2\sqrt{n}$ asymptotically? (see the comments on how to get to $2\sqrt{2n}$).

I found one similar question (for $\mathbb F_2^n$ instead of integers) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188767/minimal-sumset-basis-in-the-discrete-linear-space-mathbb-f-2n) but could not find further useful references.

Comment: Don't you get $2\sqrt n$ asymptotically by taking everything from zero to $d$, the integer part of $\sqrt n$, and then all multiples of $d$ up to $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I don't think so, if I understood your comment right. It would be hard to get things in the range $[2n-d...2n]$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. A modification gets $2\sqrt2\sqrt n$ asymptotically, which isn't good enough.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Can you say more on that modification?

Comment: Never mind, I miscalculated again. How about everything from zero to $d$, multiples of $d$ up to $n-d$, and everything from $n-d$ to $n$? That's $3\sqrt n$, asymptotically.

Comment: I think that gets us to $2\sqrt{2n}$ actually.

Comment: Does it? $\sqrt n$ up to $d$, $\sqrt n$ down to $n-d$, and $\sqrt n$ between $d$ and $n-d$, I thought.

Comment: So it is about $2d+n/d$ which minimizes at $2\sqrt{2n}$!

Comment: OK, so, that's taking $d$ roughly $\sqrt{n/2}$.

Comment: Here are the values of $m(n)$ for $n \in\{1,\dots,50\}$: 2 ,3 ,4 ,4 ,5 ,5 ,6 ,6 ,7 ,7 ,8 ,8 ,8 ,9 ,9 ,9 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,11 ,11 ,12 ,12 ,12 ,12 ,12 ,13
,13 ,13 ,14 ,13 ,14 ,14 ,14 ,14 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,15 ,16 ,16 ,16 ,16 ,16 ,16 ,17 ,17 ,17 ,17.  It doesn't seem to be in the OEIS.

Comment: @RobPratt: thanks, that's great! Did you use any special algorithm/computer? I imagine a brute force search will get large very quickly.

Comment: What the heck is going on at $n=31$?

Comment: The term to google is *additive basis*, or maybe try *additive basis for interval*.

Comment: @Seva: that looks very relevant, thanks.

Comment: Here is yet another construction which gives $|S|=2(1+o(1))\sqrt{2n}$, at least for certain values of $n$. 

Suppose that $n=2^{m}$ with $m$ odd. Let $S=\{0\}\cup S_0\cup S_1$, where $S_0$ is the set of numbers in $[1,n]$ with all non-zero binary digits in the "even positions", and $S_1$ is the set of numbers in $[1,n]$ with all non-zero binary digits in the "odd positions". It is quite obvious that $S+S$ is the subset sum set of the set $\{0,1,2,4,\dotsc,2^m\}$, which is the interval $[0,2^{m+1}]=[0,2n]$. Also, for $m$ odd, we have $|S_0|=|S_1|=2^{(m+1)/2}$, whence $|S|=2\sqrt{2n}+1$.

Comment: @Seva: I looked at some literature on additive bases, and my question can be translated to basis for $2n$ but lies inside $[n]$. Unfortunately no paper that I came across seemed to address this particular problem, and all the current records use elements in the interval $[n+1, 2n]$, which does not help immediately. Perhaps one needs to really study the techniques there.

Comment: "Perhaps one needs to really study the techniques there." - Absolutely.

Comment: Did this problem occur in some context in your work, or was it largely curiosity?  My answer settles your Question 2 in the negative.  Please let me know if you find anything there unclear, or if you were looking for something more.

Comment: @Lucia: this arose when I tried to estimate certain algebraic invariants for a class of examples. So your answer (and everyone's contributions) are very helpful. Thanks. I am not sure if more could be done. It looks like a precise answer is not possible, and I don't really need very precise estimates, just to say: "for this class of examples, this invariant is hard to compute, but  some rough estimates exist".

Comment: If you eventually write up your examples, please do link them here.  I'd be curious to see how such problems come up in commutative algebra.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. We probably would just refer to this question and answers in the example. Will probably take a few months before the paper is ready though.

Comment: Here is a closely related question which may be of interest. Perhaps Lucia's argument below can give a non-trivial improvement there too? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323294/bound-of-size-x-subset-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-which-satisfies-xx-mathbbz/323550#323550

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $S\subset [1,N]$ with $S+S=2N$.   I will show that $S$ must have at least $(2.033 +o(1))\sqrt{N}$ elements for large $N$.  The argument can certainly be improved, but I don't know what the right answer should be.

Assume that $N$ is large and that $|S| =O(\sqrt{N})$ (else we are done of course).  Let $r(n)$ denote the number of ways of writing $n$ as $a+b$ 
with $a$ and $b$ in $S$.  Apart from the cases $a=b$ which occur for at $O(\sqrt{N})$ values, we have $r(n)\ge 2$ for $n\le 2N$ (since $a+b$ and $b+a$ 
will be counted as two different solutions).  As noted in the problem, we then 
have 
$$ 
4N +O(\sqrt{N}) \le \sum_{n\le 2N} r(n) = |S|^2,  
$$ 
which gave the asymptotic bound $|S| \ge 2\sqrt{N}+O(1)$ that we now wish to improve.

Decompose $S$ into three sets $A$, $B$, $C$, where $A=S\cap[1,N/3)$, $B=S\cap[N/3,2N/3)$, and $C= S\cap[2N/3,N]$. Say $|A|=\alpha\sqrt{N}$, $|B|=\beta\sqrt{N}$ and $|C| =\gamma\sqrt{N}$, so that we know already that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma\ge 2+o(1)$.

Consider $A+A$.  This must cover all numbers in $[1,N/3]$ and therefore we must have 
$$ 
|A|^2 \ge \sum_{n\le N/3} r(n) \ge 2N/3+ O(\sqrt{N}).
$$ 
Therefore we must have 
$$ 
\alpha \ge \sqrt{2/3} +o(1). \tag{1} 
$$

Similarly $C+C$ must cover all elements in $[5N/3,2N]$ which leads to 
$$ 
\gamma \ge \sqrt{2/3}+ o(1). \tag{2}
$$

Now consider $B+B$ and $A+C$.  These sums are all in $[2N/3,4N/3]$ and therefore we obtain 
$$ 
\sum_{2N/3 \le n \le 4N/3} r(n) \ge |B|^2 + 2|A| |C| +O(\sqrt{N}) = (\beta^2+2\alpha\gamma+o(1)) N. 
$$ 
Therefore 
$$ 
|S|^2 =\sum_{n\le 2N} r(n) \ge \Big(\sum_{n< 2N/3} +\sum_{2N/3\le n\le 4N/3} +\sum_{4N/3<n \le 2N} \Big) r(n) 
$$
must be at least
$$
\Big(\frac{8}{3} + \beta^2 + 2\alpha \gamma +o(1)\Big) N. \tag{3}
$$

Put $\alpha+\gamma =2\sqrt{2/3}+\delta$, with $\delta>0$.  Since both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ must be $\ge \sqrt{2/3}+o(1)$ we must have 
$$
\alpha\gamma \ge \sqrt{2/3}(\sqrt{2/3}+\delta)+o(1) = \frac 23 +\sqrt{\frac 23}\delta +o(1).
$$
If $\delta\ge 2-2\sqrt{2/3}$, then using this in (3) we would get 
$$
|S|^2 \ge \Big( 4 +2 \sqrt{2/3} \delta+o(1)\Big) N \ge 4.599N, 
$$ 
which is more than we claimed.

Suppose then that $\delta \le 2-2\sqrt{2/3}$, so that $\beta \ge 2-(\alpha+\gamma)=2-2\sqrt{2/3}-\delta (>0)$. Using this in (3) we find 
$$ 
|S|^2 \ge \Big( 4+ 2\sqrt{2/3} \delta + (2-2\sqrt{2/3}-\delta)^2 +o(1) \Big) N.
$$
The right side is smallest for $\delta=0$, yielding 
$$
|S|^2 \ge (4+(2-2\sqrt{2/3})^2+o(1))N,
$$
which gives $|S| \ge (2.0333\ldots +o(1))\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Could you explain the fraction $8/3$ in (3)? (I can see $4/3$

Comment: @Seva:  Note that $r(n)$ is usually at least $2$.  In the display preceding (3) the first and third sums have $2N/3$ elements each; giving a total of $4N/3$ terms, and now multiply this by $2$ (the usual size of $r(n)$).

Answer (score 8):

For a fixed $n$, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming.  For $j \in [n]$, let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether $j\in S$.  For $0\le j_1\le j_2 \le n$, let binary decision variable $y_{j_1,j_2}$ indicate whether both $j_1$ and $j_2$ are in $S$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_j x_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j y_{j,i-j} &\ge 1 &&\text{for $i \in [2n]$}\\
y_{j_1,j_2} &\le x_{j_1}\\
y_{j_1,j_2} &\le x_{j_2}
\end{align}

I didn't try to find all optimal solutions, but here is one for each $n \le 50$:

```
 n  m optimal S
 1  2 {0,1}
 2  3 {0,1,2}
 3  4 {0,1,2,3}
 4  4 {0,1,3,4}
 5  5 {0,1,2,4,5}
 6  5 {0,1,3,5,6}
 7  6 {0,1,2,4,6,7}
 8  6 {0,1,3,5,7,8}
 9  7 {0,1,3,5,7,8,9}
10  7 {0,1,3,5,7,9,10}
11  8 {0,1,3,5,7,9,10,11}
12  8 {0,1,3,5,7,9,11,12}
13  8 {0,1,2,5,8,11,12,13}
14  9 {0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,14}
15  9 {0,1,3,4,9,11,12,14,15}
16  9 {0,1,2,5,8,11,14,15,16}
17 10 {0,1,3,5,7,8,13,14,16,17}
18 10 {0,1,3,5,6,12,13,15,17,18}
19 10 {0,1,2,5,8,11,14,17,18,19}
20 10 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,17,19,20}
21 11 {0,1,3,5,6,13,15,16,18,20,21}
22 11 {0,1,2,3,7,11,15,19,20,21,22}
23 12 {0,1,3,5,6,13,15,16,18,20,22,23}
24 12 {0,1,3,5,7,8,16,17,19,21,23,24}
25 12 {0,1,3,4,9,11,15,17,21,22,24,25}
26 12 {0,1,3,4,9,11,15,17,22,23,25,26}
27 12 {0,1,3,5,6,13,14,21,22,24,26,27}
28 13 {0,1,2,3,5,9,13,17,21,25,26,27,28}
29 13 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,18,23,25,26,28,29}
30 13 {0,1,3,4,6,10,14,19,21,26,27,29,30}
31 14 {0,1,2,4,7,9,10,15,20,22,27,28,30,31}
32 13 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,21,23,28,29,31,32}
33 14 {0,1,3,5,6,12,13,20,21,27,28,30,32,33}
34 14 {0,1,2,3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31,32,33,34}
35 14 {0,1,3,5,6,13,14,21,22,29,30,32,34,35}
36 14 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,20,25,27,32,33,35,36}
37 15 {0,1,3,4,7,9,14,16,21,26,28,33,34,36,37}
38 15 {0,1,2,3,4,9,14,19,24,29,31,34,35,37,38}
39 15 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,20,25,30,35,36,37,38,39}
40 15 {0,1,3,4,5,8,14,20,26,32,35,36,37,39,40}
41 16 {0,1,3,5,6,11,12,19,20,27,28,35,36,38,40,41}
42 16 {0,1,3,4,7,8,13,18,23,28,33,35,38,39,41,42}
43 16 {0,1,3,4,5,8,14,20,26,29,35,38,39,40,42,43}
44 16 {0,1,3,5,7,8,17,18,26,27,36,37,39,41,43,44}
45 16 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,20,25,29,34,36,41,42,44,45}
46 16 {0,1,3,4,5,8,14,20,26,32,38,41,42,43,45,46}
47 17 {0,1,2,5,8,9,10,15,21,27,33,39,42,43,44,46,47}
48 17 {0,1,3,4,5,8,14,20,26,32,38,39,43,45,46,47,48}
49 17 {0,1,3,4,5,8,14,20,26,32,38,41,45,46,47,48,49}
50 17 {0,1,3,4,9,11,16,20,25,30,34,39,41,46,47,49,50}
```

Comment: Ah, that's clever. While you are at it, does the program tell you how many solutions for each $n$?

Comment: After reading some literature I start to suspect that $\lim s(n)/\sqrt{n}$ might be larger than $2$. Is it possible to compute $s(100)$? Thanks.

Comment: $m(100) \in [22,25]$. Best so far is $S=  \{0,1,3,4,6,10,13,15,21,29,37,45,53,61,69,77,84,85,90,94,95,96,97,99,100\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Such a set $S$ is known as a **restricted additive basis**.

---

As observed in comments, the general term to search for is *[finite]
additive basis*: a finite set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $S+S
\supseteq [2n]$.  Another term is *[postage stamp problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PostageStampProblem.html)* (not to
be confused with the Frobenius postage stamp problem which is
different).

The extra condition that $S \subseteq [n]$ makes this the
*restricted postage stamp problem* and the solutions are *restricted
additive bases*. ("Restricted" means that the elements are restricted
to be in $[n]$.)

It is then (almost) equivalent to ask

1. given $k$, what is the largest $n$ ...
2. given $n$, what is the smallest $k$ ...

such that there exists a restricted additive basis of $k$ elements for
the interval $[2n]$.  More about that "almost" at the end of this
answer.  Let us write $n(k)$ for the largest $n$ when $k$ is given,
and $k(n)$ for the smallest $k$ when $n$ is given.

Here the question asks for $k(n)$.  For $n(k)$ this is OEIS
[A006638](https://oeis.org/A006638), where currently the largest entry is $a(47)=734$ by
yours truly (2015).  Some translation needed: That "47" counts only the
nonzero elements, so in fact there are 48 elements; that "734"
means the target interval is $[2n]=[734]$, so in our current notation
it becomes $n(48)=367$, and $k(367)=48$.

---

To the specific questions:

**Q1.** The OEIS entry gives some pointers to literature.
The oldest reference that I know is H. Rohrbach, "Ein Beitrag zur additiven
Zahlentheorie", *Math. Z.*, 42 (1937), 1-30, which studies both the
unrestricted and the restricted versions.
Symmetric bases have also been studied, see for example S. Mossige,
"Algorithms for computing the h-range of the postage stamp problem",
*Math. Comp.* 36 (1981), 575–582.

**Q2.** About asymptotics: No, one cannot achieve $k(n) \sim
2\sqrt{n}$ asymptotically.  Gang Yu, "Upper bounds for finite additive
2-bases", *Proc. AMS* 137 (2009), 11-18, shows that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{k_r(n)^2} \le 0.419822,$$

where $k_r(n)$ is the smallest size of a restricted basis for $[n]$.
I believe this is currently the best lower bound for $k_r$.
Translated to our notation (with target interval $[2n]$)
this means the factor in front of $\sqrt n$ is asymptotically at least $2.18264$.

---

And about the "almost": Generally $k(n)$ increases as $n$
increases, but there are some known cases where $k(n)$ suddenly steps
down. One of them was also noticed in the comments above: "What the
heck is going on at n=31?".  Indeed we have $k(31)=14$ but $k(32)=13$;
$k(51)=18$ but $k(52)=17$; and $k(57)=19$ but $k(58)=18$.
See Table 5 in [this 2018 paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL21/Rajamaki/raj.html) by me and coauthors, where the
corresponding problem is studied in two dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Note that any solution will be of the form  $S=\{0,1,s_2,\cdots,s_j,n-1,n\}$ and then $S'=\{0,1,n-s_j,\cdots,n-s_2,n-s_1,n-1,n\}$ is also a solution. If $S=S'$ one might call it a symmetric solution. This requires that $n$ and/or $m(n)$ is even. In any case it might be pleasant to try to maximize $|S \cap S'|.$ A possible alternate, or further, goal would be to minimize the number of distinct jumps between successive entries.Aside from aesthetics, when there are several optimal solutions, the ones with the must symmetry or regularity might be fruitful for suggesting generalizations.

In a somewhat trivial sense, for any two solutions $S_1,S_2$ of size $m(n),$ One can change $S_1$ to $S_2$ by shifting entries. So it is hard to say if one solution is essentially different from another.

Many values of $n$  (but not all) seem to have optimal solutions with this structure:

> Start with $0,1,2,\cdots, d-1=s_d$ end with $s_{d+p+1}=n-(d-1),\cdots, n-2,n-1,n$ and in the middle put entries $s_{d+1},s_{d+2},\cdots,s_{d+p}$ which satisfy $s_{i+1}-s_i \leq d$ for $d-1\leq i \leq d+p.$

This will always give a solution of size $2d+p$. For an optimal solution $d$ should be around $\sqrt{\frac{n}2}$ and $p$ as small as possible given $n,d,$ so  $p=\lceil \frac{n+2}d-3\rceil.$ In some cases there are $3$ values of $d$ which work.

---

$m(23)=12$ and one solution is $S=\{0,1,3,5,6,13,15,16,18,20,22,23\}$

There are $22$ symmetric solutions. The lower halves are

$ \left\{ 0,1,2,3,4,9 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,2,3,6,10 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,2,3,7,10 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,2,3,7,11 \right\} ,
 \mathbf{\left\{ 0,1,2,4,5,11 \right\}} , \left\{ 0,1,2,4,6,9 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,2,4,7,10 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,2,5,6,8 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,2,5,7,10 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,2,5,8,10 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,2,5,8,11 \right\} , \mathbf{\left\{ 0,1,3,4,5,11 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,3,4,6,11 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,3,4,7,9 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,3,4,8,9 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,3,4,8,10 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,3,4,9,10 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,3,4,9,11 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,3,5,6,8 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,3,5,6,10 \right\} ,
 \left\{ 0,1,3,5,6,11 \right\} , \left\{ 0,1,3,5,7,8 \right\}} $

The values of $d$ represented are $3,4,5.$ The ones in bold merit further perusal. They do not fully fit the scheme described as there are jumps greater than the relevant $d$.

---

$m(20)=10$ and the given solution $S=\{0,1,3,4,9,11,16,17,19,20\}$ is symmetric.

There are no solutions which fit the scheme above as $$6+\lceil \frac{22}3 \rceil-3=8+\lceil \frac{22}4 \rceil-3=11.$$

---

$m(38)=15$ and the solution $$S=\{0,1,2,3,4,9,14,19,24,29,31,34,35,37,38\}$$ can be shifted to give this solution 
 with $d=4$

$$S=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 36, 37, 38\}$$

and also this one with $d=5$

$$\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38\}.$$
In those cases there is no choice for the middle entries as $\frac{40}{4}-3=7$ and $\frac{40}5-3=5.$

---

For $n=2d^2-2$ there are optimal symmetric solutions with $|S|=4d-3$. These are the ones listed by Rob Pratt for $n=6,16.$

- $\{0,1,2,3,7,11,15,19,23,27,28,29,30\}$ works for $d=4.$
- $\{0,1,2,3,4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,45,46,47,48\}$ works for $d=5.$

One last example: $m(43)=16$ and one solution is $$S=\{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 14, 20, 26, 29, 35, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43\}$$

A symmetric solution is  $$S
=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43\}.$$

Comment: @LSpice You are right of course.

Comment: I guess your last two bullets are instead $d=4$ and $d=5$.

Comment: For $n \le 50$, forcing symmetry yields the same optimal values, except $m(n)+1$ for $n\in \{5,9,15,21,29,37,39,47,49\}$, which are exactly the cases where both $n$ and $m(n)$ are odd.